# selecting and moving lamp using right mouse button

Tags: workflow

I just registered in the forum and am asking my first question. I am new to Blender and 3d animation. A reference work I am using to learn Blender states that the lamp can be selected and moved by hovering the cursor over the lamp and clicking and holding the lamp with the right mouse button. When I first tried it the click kept producing a contextual menu but suddenly a RMB click did allow me to move and adjust lamp. I don't know what I did because I cannot now replicate it: a RMB click just produces a contextual menu. I am running Windows 10. Thanks for your replies.

Monty

Comment: The selection behavior in the user interface has changed significantly between versions 2.79 and 2.80 of Blender. Presumably your reference material is pre-2.80 but you're using 2.80 or later...?

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake. Using 2,81a, but the guide (Blender 3D Basics: Beginner's Guide by Gordon Fisher), which I find very easy to follow, was published in 2012 and based on ver. 2.63. Two questions. Any recommendations for a third-party guide based on current version? The video tutorials referenced by the program itself seem excellent and perhaps that should be my sole guide. Unless there is a very simple answer as to how to move the lamp, I will search those online tutorials.

Comment: I'd suggest the official Help/Tutorials guides are the best place to start - especially since it's all tailored to the correct version (a lot has changed with the leap to 2.80). Anything else, either search online or post questions on this site - there are always people happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The selection behavior in the user interface has changed significantly between versions 2.79 and 2.80 of Blender (as well as many other changes to the user interface).

Use the Help/Tutorials menu option within Blender to like to official online tutorials
and resources that will be suitable for the appropriate version of Blender.